# How can syslog work over UDP if there are critical log messages (ALERT) that cannot be lost? Also log message order is important

Tags: logging, syslog

Does syslog have any kind of reliable UDP protocol, that lost messages are re-send or something? Or can syslog be only useful over TCP? How does it solve the problem of a critical log message being lost over UDP? Or messages out of order?

Answer (score 0):

Traditional BSD Syslog was designed to be simple, not to be reliable, nor to guarantee message order.

Other Syslog implementations (such as rsyslog and syslog-ng) implement additional transport protocols, such as TCP or AMQP, which might have those properties. But even then logging is always optional, and the transport protocol itself does not change the properties of the logging system as a whole.